# Deploy Release C# windows application

Tags: c#, deployment, release

I have finished a Windows C# application and this is the first time I am going to deploy it. I have searched for many tutorials. The microsoft site tells me to use the ClickOnce method. I have also tried from the Publishing settings. After I double click and install the application successfully, once I try to open it, nothing happens!

I have left all the settings as they are in debugging stage (e.g. Configuration: Debug) and all the other publish settings are left as they are.. can some one be kind enough to provide me with a dummy tutorial as I don't have any clue where to start from. I am saving some data in a file in DEBUG/Data. What will happen to this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the "deploying option" that Microsoft's offer. because its rubbish.
I'd suggest you to do it your self, here is what I suggest:

1. Protect your source-code with obfuscation.
2. Compile your application with the release mode (F6) not the debug mode (F5).
3. Copy your compiled files from "Release" Folder.
4. Download any Freeware Installer such as "Inno Setup".
5. Pack your files with the installer.
6. Distribute your application.

you can also skip the installer part. all you need is to distribute it as a Zip file or Rar.
there are plenty of other steps can be involved depending on how heavy your application is.

Comment: F6 is only a shortcut to 'Build'. You manually have to select the 'Release' configuration before building your application

Comment: thank you very much. I am trying all these steps out :) . I will now look into 'obfuscation' too :)

Comment: @RobinVanPersi correct, I just added the comment in case someone thinks F6 is the same as 'Build for release'